# Materialize Select onChange's not calling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `onChange()` is not calling using [materializecss select](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select). :

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

**React:**

```
...

_bar: function(e){
  console.log("I was called");
},

// Render():

<select defaultValue={this.state.foo} onChange={this._bar}>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

...
```

The funny thing is, if I add the class `browser-default`, on the `select` tag, `bar()` is called. Any way around this without the class added to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you use incompatible tools. As usual, you SHOULD NOT use jquery dom functions with react, because in 90 % cases it is useless, it can break some native react logic with virtual dom, and of course it is overhead.

Try to use this library:

https://react-materialize.github.io/forms.html